# How to move state up when using React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-state

I am using the React-Native Navigation module for switching between screens. I have some state variables in my homescreen script that I need to access in my newblock script. So I tried to move my state up to access the state from both scripts. In my App.js I tried to create a state and pass it down in the Navigator component, which is imported from my Stack Navigator.

'''
import React from 'react';
import Navigator from "./Routes/homeStack"

```
export default function App() {
    const [state, onState] = React.useState("foo")

    return (
        <Navigator
            state1 = {state}
        />
   );
}
```

'''

But when I try to access state1 in my underlying homescreen, it doesn't work. So I presume that this is not the way to do it, but I couldn't find any other way to do it. Thanks in advance!

'''
< Text style={styles.title}>{props.state1}</ Text>
'''

Comment: Try using the Context API instead. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.